# How to get rid of double edge

Tags: edges

I've already applied the mirror modifier and combined all of the meshes together. When I came around to mark seams, I find double the edges on the head mesh only. How do I remove them?

[image]

Comment: the simplest way is to select all and W > Remove Doubles. You can play with the parameters on the bottom of the T panel (on the left of your 3D view)

Answer (score 2):

Select all vertices, after that press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*